# OWA Invites adds descripton and weird characters

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-access

When I send an invite, OWA (Or exchange) adds this description (in Spanish in my case)

```
Cuándo: martes, 13 de diciembre de 2016 10:00-11:00. (UTC) Hora universal coordinada

*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
```

There is a way to stop Outlook or exchage to modify my events?